# In a if/else statement. I try to do a code for defining if the number is even or odd

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have seen the if `x%2==1` and `x&2` but I don't understand how that works 
I don't understand the `x%2==1` and `x&2` means in the if statement

```
x=int(input("Write your number to define if either is even or odd"))
if x%2==1:
   print('odd')
else:
   print('even')
```

This work well but I don't understand how they define numbers

Comment: `a % b` means `a mod b` (which is math, look up what a modulo is), and `a & b` means `a BYTEWISE AND b` (which is coding, about the same as `and`, but with numbers instead of booleans)

Comment: @EthanK: I think you mean bitwise.

Comment: @EdGrimm Yes, sorry. I meant `BITWISE`.

Answer (score 0):

% represents [modulus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) which, when applied to integers, measures the remainder of dividing the numerator by the denominator.

In Python, `X % 2 == 0` is used to check whether X / 2 has a remainder or not.

Another way to think of it is, `X % 2 == 0` checks whether or not 2 is a factor of X.

```py
if X % 2 == 0:
    # 2 is a factor of X, therefore X is even
    is_even = True
else:
    # 2 is not a factor of X, therefore X is odd
    is_even = False
```